# Linux terminal on OpenELEC?

Tags: openelec, gui

I've been using OpenELEC as my personal Media Center for long. I'm aware that `OpenELEC` is a linux-based distribution.

So, is there any terminal in it or just the GUI?

Comment: I haven't used openELEC, but you could try Ctrl-alt-F[1-6] (as in try F1, then F2, etc) to see if there are the standard [virtual consoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console).  I'd hope there's a way to launch a GUI terminal too...

Comment: You also could enable `ssh` and connect from another device.

Comment: @goldilocks I tried, but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: If nothing works then there is nothing you can do, right?

Comment: OpenELEC gives you the opportunity to open the SSH port during setup for whatever reason, but when I did so, not much happed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can ssh to it or use app launcher to get a terminal but there is not much point as there is not even a package manager. For that reason I use [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/download/images/) because it's closer to a normal Debian.